# How to write log file in ios device?

Tags: c++, ios, logging, file-io

I want to write log files in iOS device provided by a C++ library. For that what can I do? I haven't found a clue. The references I have found in this site are not clear to me as I am new in this platform. I have done it easily by saving in :/var directory for jail broken device, I need to do this for non jail broken device. What should be done for this? I am really confused regarding this issue.

Comment: I suggest using [Cocoa Lumberjack](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaLumberjack)

Comment: @Rob will u explain more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it. By using the following code I have fetched the document directory of the app -

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
```

After doing this I have casted the `documentsDirectory` to C++ character pointer, and passed the directory in my C++ project. Then created the log file by using `fopen`. Its quite tricky though.

Answer (score 2):

"Cocoa Lumberjack" framework is widely used all over the world for creating logging files. You can get all information, tutorial, sample code about it by googling Cocoa Lumberjack.

Here are links for you to download cocoa lumberjack library and tutorial:

1. Framework Link: [Cocoa Lumberjack Library](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaLumberjack)
2. Tutorial: [CocoaLumberjack: Logging on Steroids](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/cocoalumberjack-logging-on-steroids/)

Comment: Ok. I will study it. But I have to write file using C++ API not Objective-C. Is it possible in Cocoa Lumberjack?

Comment: cocoa lumberjack provides you functionality to overwrite NSLog() with your own custom logging.. May be it also provides functionality to overwrite cout/printf statements. but it's not confirmed.. have to search for it

Comment: Done it without using cocoa lumberjack framework. BTW thanks.